# Why is $f(a) \neq 0$ if $a \neq 0$ with $f$ being a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

I tried to prove it via contradiction, but I still need $f$ to be injective.
Here is what I tried:

$$
f(a) = 0 = f(0),
$$
thus $a = 0$ (only if $f$ is injective), which leads to a contradiction. How do I generalize this for all ring homomorphisms?

Comment: What is the definition of ring homomorphism you are using?

Comment: $$f(1) = 1, 
f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b), 
 f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$$

Comment: The reason you haven’t been able to prove it is that it’s not true. Consider the ring homomorphism defined on $\Bbb Z$ that sends odd integers to $1$, evens to zero, in the ring with two elements $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks very much

Comment: In fact this is only true for injective homomorphisms, since $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in\ker f$